# How to close controllerView on button click?

Tags: swift

I use `navigation.pushViewController` to open a ViewController, the opened Storyboard has a close button, I use `navigation.popViewController` to close it, but it doesn't work neither it shows an error, full code below:

```
import UIKit

class ConfirmKycViewController: UIViewController {
    private unowned let navigation: UINavigationController? = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
            
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func CloseViewController(_ sender: Any) {
        navigation?.popViewController(animated: true)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Thank you for help

Comment: `navigation`? Why do you use that? I guess it's not set, why not use `navigationController` directly? Also, is `CloseViewController(_:)` called? You pop & dismiss at the same time?

Comment: I am new in Swift, could you please elaborate or leave an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change `navigation?.popViewController(animated: true)` with `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`